# How to get menuitem array's index?

Tags: cocos2d-js

I want to get an index of menuItem.

How can I get it in the menuItem function?

```
        var button=[];
        var menu;
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            button[i]=new cc.MenuItemImage(
                res.ball_png,
                res.ball_png,
                function(){
                    cc.log(i);   // this part
                },this);
            button[i].setTag(i);
            button[i].x=100*i;
        }
        menu=new cc.Menu(button);
        this.addChild(menu);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself.

```
var button=[];
        var menu;
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
            button[i]=new cc.MenuItemImage(
                res.ball_png,
                res.ball_png,
                function(val){
                    cc.log(val.getTag());
                },this);
            button[i].setTag(i);
            button[i].x=100*i;
        }
        menu=new cc.Menu(button);
        this.addChild(menu);
```